# Does anyone know the equivalent DDRC register on Arduino for the one on ESP32?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

Dear StackOverflowers,

I am interested in making an acoustic levitation DIY project but I have an esp32 qC and I don't know the equivalent DDRC register for that. The follow code is given:

```
//made by milespeterson101
//published on 6/17/2022
//heres the code (:

byte TP = 0b10101010; // Every other port receives the inverted signal
void setup() {
  DDRC = 0b11111111; // Set all analog ports to be outputs
  
  // Initialize Timer1
  noInterrupts(); // Disable interrupts
  
  TCCR1A = 0;
  TCCR1B = 0;
  TCNT1 = 0;
  OCR1A = 200; // Set compare register (16MHz / 200 = 80kHz square wave -> 40kHz full wave)
  
  TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12); // CTC mode
  TCCR1B |= (1 << CS10); // Set prescaler to 1 ==> no prescaling
  TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A); // Enable compare timer interrupt
  
  interrupts(); // Enable interrupts
}
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
  PORTC = TP; // Send the value of TP to the outputs
  TP = ~TP; // Invert TP for the next run
}
void loop() {
  // Code ends here (:
}
```

more details about the project here:
https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/milespeterson101/ultrasonic-levitation-acoustic-levitation-experiment-8050f8

Thanks in advance!

I thought it would work withouth any code modifications but unfortunately I got stuck at this point.

Comment: That project was done on an Uno, and the code is nice, but hardware specific.
Easiest you get a nano clone and use your esp32 for other tasks, which use its features better. You won't be able to do levitation and wifi in parallel, I fear :)

Comment: For ESP32 GPIO manipulation, see [ESP-IDF GPIO](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/gpio.html).

Answer (score -2):

Im not sure if it can be done with interrupts, but this code should do almost the same as yours. The time period of a 40Khz signal is 12.5uS, so checking if has passed 12uS should be closed.

```
        #define bit7 15
    #define bit6 2
    #define bit5 4
    #define bit4 16
    #define bit3 17
    #define bit2 5
    #define bit1 18
    #define bit0 19
    
    
    long int t0 = 0;
    long int t1 = 0;
    bool ledStatus = false;
    
    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      pinMode(bit7, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(bit6, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(bit5, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(bit4,OUTPUT);
      pinMode(bit3,OUTPUT);
      pinMode(bit2, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(bit1,OUTPUT);
      pinMode(bit0, OUTPUT);
    
      t0 = micros();
      
    
    }
    
    void loop() {
      t1 = micros();
      if(t1 > (t0+12)){
        digitalWrite(bit7, ledStatus);
        digitalWrite(bit6, ledStatus);
        digitalWrite(bit5, ledStatus);
        digitalWrite(bit4, ledStatus);
        digitalWrite(bit3, ledStatus);
        digitalWrite(bit2, ledStatus);
        digitalWrite(bit1, ledStatus);
        digitalWrite(bit0, ledStatus);
    
        ledStatus = !ledStatus;
        t0 = micros();
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @rubenestradamarmolejo, but unfortunately the code you sent didn't work for me. However, one of my friends sent me this one which worked:

`void setup() {
  ledcSetup(0,40000,8);
  ledcAttachPin(14,0);
  ledcWrite(0, 0x7F);
  
  ledcSetup(1,40000,8);
  ledcAttachPin(15,1);
  ledcWrite(1, 0x7F);
  GPIO.func_out_sel_cfg[15].inv_sel = 1;
}

void loop()`